# Unzipping Multiple zip files using 7zip command line

Tags: unzip, 7zip

I have a number of zip files located in a single folder eg:

file1.gz
file2.gz
file3.gz
file4.gz

I'm looking for a way of automatically unzipping these using a batch job to a similarly named folder structure so for example the contents of file1.gz will drop into a folder named file1.

I have been told that 7zip would address my issue but can't figure out how to go about it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using? This is something you'd do using the shell's capabilities, you could write

```
for A in *.gz ; do gunzip $A ; done
```

I'm using gunzip here, because `.gz` is actually gzip, But you can use the 7zip CLI tool as well, of course. If you're on Windows, then I recommend installing a real shell (the standard cmd.exe can not really be considered a shell IMHO).

Comment: Hi - I'm using Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: @user3737374: There's the Windows Power Shell. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx – Or you could install Cygwin. I always like to have my trusted Unix tools around, even in a Windows environment, simply for situaitions like this one.

Comment: How would you suggest performing the above task using powershell ?

Comment: What i have so far is a .bat that runs the following: 
for %%A in (*.gz) do gzip $A ; done

It seems to loop through each of the 5 .gz files that are listed in the same directory but throws up an error against each that states:

%$A: No such file or directory
;: No such file or directory
done: No such file or directory